# How do I get Windows to remember the last directory used using tkinter filedialog?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Having code like:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

image_formats= [("JPEG", "*.jpg"), ("All files", "*.*")]

file=filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=image_formats)
```

I can open a file dialog box which leads me to a .jpg file.
On my Windows 7 development box this remembers over closing and opening the program the directory -- easy allowing selecting multiple files from the directory.

However, after distribution, using cx_Freeze and its bdist_msi option, the same program to a Windows 10 machine the directory is no longer remembered. How do I get the Windows 7 behaviour on the Windows 10 system? Preferably I do not perform this manually but rely on the underlying Windows mechanism.

PS Full bdist_msi distribution of the actual program is available at https://sites.google.com/site/klamerschutte/system/app/pages/admin/revisions?wuid=wuid:gx:403dfb9983518218

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I happened to run into this issue recently. I tried this with the latest version of Python 3.7.

My way around this: Just don't add an `initialdir` argument. On Windows 10, it will start from the last used directory when the filedialog is called.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly you want to know how to set the initial starting directory whenever the dialog is shown for selecting a file (of whatever types).

You may set this by the `initialdir` argument to `askopenfilename` which will take the path of the starting directory you want.

For example if I always wanted the dialog to open to the user's home folder then I could use `os.path.expanduser('~')` as the `initialdir` argument.

If you want it to remember the last directory used then get the parent directory of the file selected from the dialog using `os.pardir` and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code, it will remember the last directory used by the tool

```
filename = askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Choose template file', filetypes =[('Excel Files', '*.xlsx')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
CORRECTION:

1. create a pages_to_connect_pages.py to allow variables go inside any class (from stackoverflow, I don´t remember the reference, sorry)
   2.create a default directory in never_opened_directory.txt, to use first time
2. last_opened_directory.txt is created when you open a directory
3. use their references in pages_to_connect_pages.py
4. insert references in main app as bellow

[![create this file and all variables go to any class using Pages.something (took from stackoverflow, dont remember where from) ][1]][1]

[![create files to "remember" last directory opened after main app is closed][2]][2]
in main app:

### my_app

from pages_to_connect_pages import Pages

```
# we see if the file last_opened_directory.txt is empty(never used)
```

filesize = os.path.getsize("last_opened_directory.txt")

```
    # if Pages.last_opened_directory == '':

    if filesize == 0:
        Pages.never_opened_directory = open("never_opened_directory.txt", "r")
        directory_to_open = Pages.never_opened_directory.read()
        Pages.never_opened_directory.close()

    # elif Pages.last_opened_directory != '':
    elif filesize != 0:
        Pages.last_opened_directory = open("last_opened_directory.txt", "r")
        directory_to_open = Pages.last_opened_directory.read()
        Pages.last_opened_directory.close()

    else:
        pass
```

reference:[Python save variable even after closing the gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69014507/python-save-variable-even-after-closing-the-gui)

Answer (score -1):

If you want askopenfilename to remember last used directory, set initialdir to a nonexistent folder, something like `initialdir = "/áéá"`.
This works for me on Windows 10.