# Python save variable even after closing the gui

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I want to write a GUI and save the variables even after closing and reopening the GUI.
How can I save the variables in a way that they don't get lost after closing the app?

Comment: Once the program exists it releases everything stored in RAM. You'll need to save to a persistent storage; i.e. a file.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are stored in ram, so when the program closes, it loses all that data. you need to save it somewhere that data can stay permanently, such as on your disc in a file. here is a way to do that.

Save to file...

```
file = open("save.txt","w")
file.write(variable_you_want_to_save)
file.close()
```

Read file and store text in variable...

```
file = open("save.txt","r")
file_text = file.read()
file.close()
```

Comment: What do I do if I have more than one variable to save? I have many entry field with numbers. They should reapear when ever I reopen the app

Comment: The easiest way is just to add more files. or you can just write a list of variables to the file and split them up on read. example: file.write(str([var1,var2]))

Comment: and to read: 

file_list = eval(file.read())